# Xcode 4.1: issue navigator shows resolved errors; can they be removed?

Tags: xcode

I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.1 and are having an annoying problem:

I first got 4 errors labeled "Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'aView'", which was perfectly fine since I had forgotten to declare aView, but when I, instead of declaring aView, changed the method so that aView was no longer needed (and "aView" is not mentioned anywhere in the method), the errors still remain...

The errors don't seem to make a difference, I can compile the code and run it but the  errors are still there in the issue navigator.

Is this a bug in Xcode or is there some issue here that I haven't understood? I would very much like to get rid of the error messages if they are faulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change "LLVM GCC 4.2" to "Apple LLVM compiler 2.1" in Build Settings of your Target.

Comment: It just disappeared on it's own when I had to force quit xCode, but I'll try it out if it appears again. Thanks!